# simple query in hibernate takes a lot of time

Tags: java, hibernate, delay

I have the follow statement in java which is called 500 times and it takes about 5 minutes to complete:

```
List<Items> itemList =  session.createCriteria(Items.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("id", itemID))
    .setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("query.DBMSItems")
    .list();
```

I set on the configuration:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
```

and on the cache:

```xml
<cache
    name="query.DBMSItems"
    maxElementsInMemory="500000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="6000"
    timeToLiveSeconds="60000"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    statistics="true" />
```

Hence looks like the cache is not working.

Any explanation of why this is happening will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In second level cache, you're caching the query as key and the result as value. If you will execute the query with different parameters, each query will first be executed against the database and take the time it needs, then it will return the values and store the proper key-value pair in cache, and on several calls to the same query with same parameters then it will go to the second level cache.

A better solution for your case would be to cache your data first and then perform the queries against the data in cache.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, if instead of query for one parameter I query for more than one parameter, that is .add(Restrictions.eq("id", itemID))
.add(Restrictions.eq("name", itemID)).add(Restrictions.eq("value", itemID)) then the second cache will kick in ?

Comment: @PepitoGomiz the second query cache kicks in per query against the database. The process is directly described in the post and looks like this won't solve your problem. You can also query all the data you need, store it in an in-memory database and query this database instead of your real database engine.

Comment: What is weird is that if I remove those calls to this method the process speed up tremendously. There are not intermediate calls, the calls are direct and that is why I use cache because I could not find any other explanation.

Comment: @PepitoGomiz I would recommend editing your question and showing how this works with high speed and what you add so this becomes slow.

Answer (score 0):

5 minutes for 500 items is very slow... Before making workarounds like caching it would be better to find root cause. Try to profile you application, I recommend YourKit.

Comment: Seems like a database issue, thus caching seems the proper solution for this case, but this isn't the right approach either.

Comment: I agree, most likely it is database issue, but database can be optimized too :)

Comment: I have confronted a similar case and even database indexes won't solved the problem. For big amounts of data and several requests, it is better to move the data into cache rather than (think you're) *tuning* your database.